# Optimizing a dice roll in Yahtzee

Tags: probability, dice

Say the only score boxes you have available in the middle of a Yahtzee game are fives and fours from the upper section and it's your turn. Your initial roll gives you one five and one four, the rest being something else. For the next throw, which dices would be the best to save (not throw again) for maximizing the chances for best points for the rest of the game?

You may disregard the chance for the upper section bonus (the player has already received it or is ineligible for it) and Yahtzee bonuses. The only ways to get points at this point would be from the fives and fours themselves.

The game ends when there are no players with available score boxes. Because this question is about optimizing one's own score, it should be irrelevant whether the game is played solitaire or with other players. A Yahtzee turn consists of initial dice roll (all five dices are rolled) and two corrective rolls, where the player can freely choose which dices they want to roll and which to save. Only the initial roll is required and the player may choose to register their points to any available score box at any point after the initial roll, meaning after the initial roll, after the first corrective roll or after the second corrective roll. The turn ends when a score box is used and becomes unavailable. Score box of fives gives n * 5 points where n equals the number of fives in the player's dice row and score box of fours gives n * 4 points where n equals the number of fours in the player's dice row.

Comment: I think you need to add more relevant details about the game, e.g. what the 'best points' are and what triggers the end of the game

Comment: This is a rather tedious question.  It basically boils down to "should the 4 or the 5 be kept after this first roll?" and "under what conditions should one swap from keeping the number we had originally kept from the first roll to the other number in the second/third rolls."  My instinct is that you should keep the five and aim for fives initially, but if on the second roll you get two or more fours, swap to keeping those instead for the third roll and score fours.  Otherwise, keep collecting fives and score those.  Then for the following round blindly aim to collect as many of the other num.

Comment: In the full game, additional considerations should come into play, such as whether or not the player is eligible for the bonus points from the top half and how away from earning those bonus points they are or whether or not second or third yahtzees will trigger bonus points and effectively extend the game giving you more rounds.  For instance, if on the first round we opted to go for $5$'s and we score $5$'s, in the second round we would ordinarily think to blindly go for $4$'s... but if we had rolled four $5$'s on the first roll, we might choose to try for that fifth five and risk zero points

Comment: I also think it's barely possible that you would keep *both* the 4 and the 5, to maximize the chance you get a double or triple of either number at the second roll. I think it's pretty clear from the second roll you just keep whichever one you have more of - and the tiebreak is also unclear to me (is 1/5 hits in the first roll good enough to take the 5s on?)